# POSIX regular expressions - `.*?` is still greedy

Tags: c, regex, posix

I want to extract some part of string and include into array. Here is my current code:

```
  int r;
  regex_t reg;
  regmatch_t match[2];
  char *line = "[ Page 1 ]  [ Page 2asdasdasd  asdas ] [ asdasdas asdas ]";

  regcomp(&reg, "[[](.*?)[]]", REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);
  /*                                ^------^ capture page number */
  r = regexec(&reg, line, 2, match, 0);
  if (r == 0) {
    printf("Match!\n");
    printf("0: [%.*s]\n", match[0].rm_eo - match[0].rm_so, line + match[0].rm_so);
    printf("1: %.*s\n", match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so, line + match[1].rm_so);
  } else {
    printf("NO match!\n");
  }
```

This will result with this:

```
1:  Page 1 ]  [ Page 2asdasdasd  asdas ] [ asdasdas asdas
```

I need to get something like this:

```
array("Page 1", "Page 2asdasdasd  asdas", "asdasdas asdas");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Non-greedy quantifiers don't exist in POSIX regex. To solve your problem, use a character class that excludes the closing square bracket instead of the dot.

Comment: Extended RE is not the same as Perl-Compatible RE.